# Integral over absolute values and null function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be continous. How can I show that
$$
\int_a^b |f(x)|dx=0\text{ iff }f(x)=0\text{ f.a. }x\in [a,b]
$$

Comment: Is $f$ continuous? What have you tried?

Comment: If $f$ is not continuous the result is true only almost everywhere

Comment: Yes, $f$ is continuous. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming $f$ is continuous:**

Let $F$ be a primitive of $|f|$ on $[a,b]$, Since $|f|\geqslant 0$, $F$ is increasing and $a<b$ implies that $F(a)\leqslant F(b)$. Thus, $\int_a^b |f(x)|dx \geqslant 0$.

If $\int_a^b |f(x)|dx = 0$ then $F(a)=F(b)$ and since $F$ is increasing, it is constant over $[a,b]$ therefore its derivative $|f|$ is zero.

The reciprocal is fairly obvious.